# Salesforce. API Connection. How to make the correct JSON?

Tags: json, salesforce

I created a API-connection.
I want to transfer candidate data for a vacancy via API.

Everything works well except some fields.

I have for these fields - empty.

- Field `msf__Recruitment_Channel__c`
  [image]
- all metadata for field
  [image]
  [image]

My JSON

```
{
    "setApiName": "default",
    "fields": {
        "visitor_id": {
            "value": "__00D9Q000000ft2GUAQ"
        },
        "Initialen": {
            "value": "dhr"
        },
        "Voornaam": {
            "value": "Zoef"
        },
        "Tussenvoegsels": {
            "value": "de"
        },
        "Achternaam": {
            "value": "Haas"
        },
        "Email": {
            "value": "zoefzoef28@gmail.com"
        },
        "Mobiel_nummer": {
            "value": "0031(0)622233333"
        },
        "Huidige_straat": {
            "value": "straat2"
        },
        "msf__Driving_License__c": {
            "value": "Yes"
        },
        "PrivacyAgreement": {
            "value": true
        },
        "msf__Recruitment_Channel__c": {
            "value": "My website"
        }
    }
}
```

How I can transfer data for field `msf__Recruitment_Channel__c`?

Answer (score 0):

Hoe gaat het ;) Next time maybe switch the language in SF to English before taking the screenshots.

It "should work" (TM). It's just a stupid picklist, it's not marked as restricted... Is your user licensed to use that msf managed package? If you're able to set `msf__Driving_License__c` OK the answer is yes.

The fields you're sending look weird. You aren't using normal Salesforce REST API, right? because  it'd require `LastName`, not `Achternaam`. There's no standard field `visitor_id`...

If your API endpoint contains "apexrest" in the URL - a salesforce developer wrote a piece of code for you and exposed it as a service. It's possible they're simply ignoring the field you're passing or maybe they expect you to pass the field label as the json field and they'll map it themselves to the real API name. "Smort". So... you'd have to go back to them and ask how this value should be passed. Or (if it's not too sensitive) you could edit your question & paste the service's code here, we could try to figure it out.